# Button with image without the regular button shape: Android

Tags: android, uibutton, imagebutton

I have an image which I want to use as a button. But I want only the image to be visible as the button, with the shape of the image (I do not want the regular button around the image, nor I want the regular button shape). How can I achieve this? Can I achieve this without  designing a custom button?

Comment: Thanks guys.. I was able to achieve what I wanted by using   android:background="@null"    for the <ImageButton> element

Comment: I have also achieved this by taking `<ImageView>` which dont require any attribute to set just need imagepath ; just set path in `android:src` attribute in `xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [android developers reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) and [Tutorial Custom Button](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton). It's exactly what you need!

Comment: Thanks Marco.. I learnt using android:background="@null" for the <ImageButton> element solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set the image with button.setBackgroundDrawable (or Resource, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton with background property set to some color i.e. #000 and no padding

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```